# Python ValueError if running on different laptop

Tags: python, pandas, merge, valueerror

I've just built a function that is working fine on my laptop (Mac, but I'm working on a Windows virtual machine of the office laptop), but when I pass it to a colleague o'mine, it raises a ValueError:

"You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat"

The line of the code that raises the error is a simple merge that on my laptop works perfectly:

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = "x", how = "outer)

The input files are exactly the same (taken directly from the same remote folder).
I totally don't know how to fix the problem, and I don't understand why on my laptop it works (even if I open a new script or I restart the kernel, so no stored variables around) and in the one of my colleague it doesn't.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is the input file type? (Excel, CSV, ...) Also: the merge is on columns coming from 2 different input files?

Comment: input are txt files opened with pd.read_csv(filename, sep = "\t"). The merge is on columns from two different files yeah

Comment: Please be careful with the accepted solution: converting to string may cause values that were equal as numbers to be different as string. E.g., suppose the problem is caused by a space in one or more values of the column that ends up being non-numeric on your colleagues computer. Suppose that your version of pandas, which is newer, ignores spaces. On your computer, the value with a space could be equal to the same _numeric_ value without a space. Once converted to string the values would be different. What is worse, is that this can go completely unnoticed until it causes damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the column is an object data type and the other is an integer. They need to be the same format in order to merge. Try adding two lines to change the data type on your colleague's computer.

```
df2['x'] = df2['x'].astype(str)
df1['x'] = df1['x'].astype(str)
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = "x", how = "outer)
```

The behavior is probably different because of a different version of pandas; or, potentially, there are slight nuances in the excel file, where the excel file on your colleague's computer has one of the columns saved in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

my guess (a wild guess) is that the data from the 2 tab-separated CSV files (i.e., TSV files) is somehow converted using different locales on your computer and your colleague's computer.

Check if you have locale-dependent operations that could cause a number with the "wrong" decimal separator not to be recognized as a number.

This should not happen in `pd.read_csv()` because the `decimal` parameter has a well-defined default value of `"."`.

But from an experience I had with timestamps in another context, one timestamp with a "bad" format can cause the whole column to be of the wrong type. So if just one number of just one of the two files, in the column you are merging on, has a decimal separator, and this decimal separator is only recognized as such on your machine, only on your machine the join will succeed (I'm supposing that pandas can join numeric columns even if they are of different type).

Comment: Thanks for the help, no decimals, only int, we solved by converting everything into strings. Actually we checked the version of pandas and mine is 1.0.1, hers is 0.23.1, could be that the reason?

Comment: yes, although the reason why the datatype ends up different for the "same" column in the two files should be investigated. Another possible problem I can think of is the number of digits of the ints. Still another is the presence of space characters (their handling could have changed between pandas versions).